# Linq - how can I use a function in a query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I use C# on WP7 (Mango). I try to use a special query because I receive an error:

> Method 'Int32 orderBirthday(System.DateTime)' has no supported
>   translation to SQL.

Yes, I know... Linq can't use my function but I don't know the right way...

I have a database table with the columns `name` and `birthday`. In my query I will calculate how many days are to the next birthday (from all items) and then I will order with "descending".

```
static int orderBirthday(DateTime Birthday)
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime birthday = Birthday;
        DateTime next = new DateTime(today.Year, birthday.Month, birthday.Day);

        if (next < today)
            next = next.AddYears(1);

        int numDays = (next - today).Days;

        // No Conversion
        return numDays;
    }

 public void LoadCollectionsFromDatabase()
    {

        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

        var toDoItemsInDB = from ToDoItem todo in toDoDB.Items
                            let daysToBirthday = orderBirthday(todo.ItemDate)
                            orderby daysToBirthday ascending
                            select todo;

        // Query the database and load all to-do items.
        AllToDoItems = new ObservableCollection<ToDoItem>(toDoItemsInDB);
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You either have to pull everything from the database and sort it locally (as Enigmativity) shows, or find a way to express the sort operation in a LINQ statement itself. And since you extracted the sorting behavior into its own function, you probably want to reuse this logic. In that case your best bet is to create a function that filters an `IQueryable`.

Here is an example of how to do this:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<Item> OrderByBirthday(
    this IQueryable<Item> items)
{
    return
        from item in items
        let today = DateTime.Today
        let birthday = item.ItemDate
        let next = new DateTime(today.Year, birthday.Month, birthday.Day)
        let next2 = next < today ? next.AddYears(1) : next
        orderby (next - today).Days
        select item;
}
```

You can use the method as follows:

```
var toDoItemsInDB = OrderByBirthday(toDoDB.Items);
```

Or you can use it as an extension method:

```
var toDoItemsInDB = toDoDB.Items.OrderByBirthday();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy if you do this:

```
    var toDoItemsInDB = from ToDoItem todo in toDoDB.Items.ToArray()
                        let daysToBirthday = orderBirthday(todo.ItemDate)
                        orderby daysToBirthday ascending
                        select todo.;
```

Notice the `.ToArray()` added to `Items`. You basically bring the results into memory and them your function can work.

Comment: But if you do that you loose the streaming ability of Linq... this could cause an OutOfMemoryException if there are many results. You should use AsEnumerable instead of ToArray

Comment: Please note that this will start performing bad when the number of records in the `Items` table starts increasing, because you will load the *complete* contents of that table into memory.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque - I don't like `AsEnumerable` - it doesn't do anything and you can still cast back to the underlying type. It's a silly implementation.

Comment: @Enigmativity, AsEnumerable doesn't do anything, really? It changes the (static) type of the sequence from `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable`, so that all subsequent Linq operators will be taken from `Enumerable` instead of `Queryable`, so the query will be executed in memory rather than in the DB. Even if its implementation is trivial, I don't think you can say that it "doesn't do anything"... Regarding casting to the underlying type: OK, so what is the underlying type of `toDoItemsInDB `? It's an internal type from the System.Core assembly, you can't cast to it since it's not accessible...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque - The implementation for `AsEnumerable` is this: `public static IEnumerable<TSource> AsEnumerable<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) { return source; }`. That's why I say it does nothing. Unless we're talking about a different `AsEnumerable` then all that it does is cast.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I know the implementation, and I insist: it does something, as I explained in my previous comment. It changes the compile-time type of the sequence, causing different methods to be called. If you prefer, it "hides" the fact that the sequence is actually an IQueryable, so that Enumerable methods are used instead.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque - It's effect is the same as casting to `IEnumerable<T>`, nothing more, right? Which, yes, does cause evaluation of the list, but it is still delayed and it still requires the database context to be alive. And I can negate the call by doing this: `var q2 = q1.AsEnumerable() as IQueryable<T>;`. It is just a cast.

Comment: If you use `AsEnumerable`, `toDoItemsInDB` will **not** be an IQueryable... so if you do `toDoItemsInDB as IQueryable<T>`, it will return null

Comment: @ThomasLevesque - Try this code: `var q1 = (new List<int>()).AsQueryable(); Console.WriteLine(q1.GetType()); var q2 = q1.AsEnumerable() as IQueryable<int>; Console.WriteLine(q2.GetType()); Console.WriteLine(q1.Equals(q2));`. The variable `q2` is not null, in fact it is the same instance as `q1`.

Comment: In that case, yes, but it doesn't apply to the OP's query. Anyway, believe what you want, I won't try to convince you any further ;)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque - No worries. It's good having a forum for lively chats like this one. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

One: Pull it from Linq2SQL to Linq2Objects using `ToEnumerable()`, and then use `orderBirthday` at the C# level.

Advantage is that it's simple to code and maintain, disadvantage is that it **can** be less efficient (depends on just what you are doing.

Two: Write an equivalent function in SQL, let's say it was called `dbo.orderBirthday`. Make your `orderBirthday` method a non-static method of your datacontext-derived class, and then mark your method as having a SQL function equivalent:

```
[Function(Name="dbo.orderBirthday",IsComposable=true)] //IsComposable is true for functions that can be used within queries, false for stored procedures that must be called on their own.
public int OrderBirthday([Parameter(Name="@birthday",DbType="datetime") DateTime birthday)
{
    return Helper.OrderBirthday(birthday); // just to show that we can keep the static version around if we want and call into it. Alternatively we could just move the whole body here.
}
```

Here the C# code is used in a non-Linq2SQL context, and the SQL code is used in composing a SQL query in a Linq2SQL context.

Advantage: Can stay within SQL longer. Disadvantage: Two versions of the same method can fall out of sync and cause bugs.

It's also possible to have the C# code call the SQL code all the time:

```
[Function(Name="dbo.orderBirthday",IsComposable=true)]
public int OrderBirthday([Parameter(Name="@birthday",DbType="datetime") DateTime birthday)
{
    return (int)ExecuteMethodCall(this, (MethodInfo)MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod(), birthday).ReturnValue;
}
```

Advantage: Keeps one version (the SQL) as the only version, so it can't fall out of synch with the C# version. Disadvantage: Calls SQL even when working on objects that have nothing to do with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to load all the items in memory and you want the database execute the calculation, you can write a stored procedure that can execute complex calculation and call the procedure using ADO or EF.