# How to call a method in the where clause of a LINQ query on a IQueryable object

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have an IQueryable of MyType obtained via EF 4.1.

I am applying filters via linq in the form of a where clause, One of which will filter based on distance from a given zip code.

MyType has a ZipCode property and I need to call a method which computes the distance between the MyType zip codes and my given zip code.

I have tried the following, which compiles, but throws an error at runtime.

```
myTypes = myTypes.Where(x => GetDistance(x.Zip, givenZip) < 10);
```

How can I accompish this?

**EDIT**

My Distance method returns a double that represents the distance in miles

```
public double Distance(Position position1, Position position2)
{ 

}
```

Position is a struct containing doubles for lat and long

Comment: Could you share how you implemented the GetDistance method, and what error you get at runtime?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq - how can I use a function in a query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874025/linq-how-can-i-use-a-function-in-a-query)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work in Linq to Objects if `GetDistance()` returns a boolean - it will not work with Linq to Entities since it will try to map your method to a SQL equivalent, which of course there is none.

As a crude workaround you could use `AsEnumerable()` but that would materialize all your types so is not recommended if your table is larger:

```
myTypes = myTypes.AsEnumerable()
                 .Where(x => GetDistance(x.Zip, givenZip) < 10);
```

Another way would be to map Zip codes to geographic locations in the database and use those locations directly with the [soon to be supported spatial data types](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/05/04/spatial-types-in-the-entity-framework.aspx) - this is probably the best approach in my opinion, but not production-ready. Of course if you are restricted to just SQL Server you could just use a store query directly to use geo-locations - but that would work around EF.

Comment: Those newly supported spatial data types will be supported in .NET 4.5. They are not yet supported in any release suitable for production.

Comment: thanks, i just changed to .AsEnumerable() its resolved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

This will throw an error because the runtime tries to convert your expression tree into SQL. The function 'GetDistance' cannot be converted.

Have a look at [Model Defined Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456857.aspx). They allow you to define a custom function in your edmx which you can execute when building queries.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
List<myType> myTypes;
```

try:

```
myTypes = myTypes.Where(x => GetDistance(x.Zip, givenZip) < 10).ToList();
```